# Inserting calculated column into existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, where-clause, alter-table

I have a column with a string of text inside of it that varies in length. I want to return the first 4 characters in the string starting from position 1 and output them into a table only if there is a direct match. So if I want to return just PDFG and not return ADHR or any other combination then the below code works just fine for me.

```
use DB
select 
substring(description, 1, 4) as newcol from table1 where substring(description, 1, 4) like '%ABCD%'
```

however I would like to persist this calculated column into an existing table, so something like this;

```
use DB
alter table table1
add newcol as ("and then the rest of the code above")
```

I am not sure how to reorder my code to fit the new query any help is appreciated.

Here is some sample data:

- PDFG_2013 AHSDHDF
- ADHR_2310 ADGDGEE
- DATW_5142 NFBSAEE

The output from this should be stored in newcol within an existing table called table1. The only value in new column from the sample data should be PDFG

Comment: Do you mean `XYZABCDEQWE` should give you `XYZA`?

Comment: @jarlh i mean the text doesnt really matter to much the strings all vary in length and are all different so some more specific example could be:
PDFG_2013 HJDSSDB
DSTV_2615 GDFSTSS
So i only want to return PDFG and not any of the other strings if there is no match but i need to store this calculated column in an existing table

Comment: But does it matter where in the string the ABCD is?

Comment: Show us some sample data - and the expected newcol values.

Comment: @jarlh i have edited the question to include an example

Comment: What do you want for each value?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `case` expression to return the first 4 characters if matching, otherwise null.

```
Alter table table1
add newcol as case when description like 'ABCD%' then substring(description, 1, 4) end
```

Or, even simplier

```
Alter table table1
add newcol as case when description like 'ABCD%' then 'ABCD' end
```